# Filtering Powershell output

Tags: powershell, filter, output

I am trying to filter the output of the following PS script;

We use server names like:

SRV-APP-001,
PRD-APP-001,
TST-APP-001
etc...

```
$strCategory = "computer" 
$strOperatingSystem = "Windows*Server*" 

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry 

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain

$objSearcher.Filter = ("OperatingSystem=$strOperatingSystem") 

$colProplist = "name" 
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)} 

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults) 
    { 
    $objComputer = $objResult.Properties;  
    $objComputer.name
    }
```

The output of this script are all the servers in the Domain.

But I want only see the servers that start with "SRV" or "PRD"

the `| where { $_name -like "SRV*"}` is not realy working after the `$objComputer.name` part.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please don't use [Hungarian Notation](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-do-not-do-powershell-part-5). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the filter to:

```
"(|(name=SRV*)(name=PRD*))(OperatingSystem=Windows*Server*)"
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't realy get it to work with that line of code or samples of it. Do I have to apply it after/in '$objSearcher.Filter = ("OperatingSystem=$strOperatingSystem")' ?

Comment: $objSearcher.Filter = "(|(name=SRV*)(name=PRD*))(OperatingSystem=Windows*Server*)"